# find and compare characters in two strings

Tags: c++

```
// if (var1.substr (0, 2) == alphaLetter[i])
```

This `if` is not legal. Is it possible somehow to check the first 3 characters in `var1` are in `alphaLetter`?

```
int main ()
{
    std::string const alphaLetter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTVUYWQZX";

    std::string var1= "";
    std::cout << " Enter 6 characters: ";
    std::cin >> var1;
    for (int i = 0; i < alphaLetter.size (); i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < alphaLetter.size(); n++)
        {
            if (var1.substr (0, 2) == alphaLetter[i])
            {
                std::cout << "True";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for string::find() ?

Comment: Your code never uses `n`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (var1.substr(0, 3).find_first_not_of(alphaLetter) == std::string::npos) {
  // The first three characters are all present in alphaLetter
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer Igor, as a beginer, I have no idea what is npos.. but I will google it. Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
if (var1.substr (0, 2) == alphaLetter[i])
```

That's illegal, because you try to compare `std::string` (with length 2) and `char`.

You can use `find_first_not_of` method ([docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of)):

```cpp
auto pos = var1.find_first_not_of(alphaLetter);
if (pos == std::string::npos ||  // means there's no letters not in alphaLetter
    pos >= 3)
{
    ...
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to find out if a `char` is in range `A..Z` you can check if it's code is in range `ord(A)..ord(Z)`:

```
auto firstThreeLetters = var1.substr(0, 3);
if (std::all_of(firstThreeLetters.begin(), firstThreeLetters.end(),
    [](char c) {
        return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
    })
{
    ...
}
```

That's faster, because `find_first_not_of` iterates over `alphaLetter` for each letter of string at the worst case.